# Ruby on rails validates with code not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a mistake here? I want the entry to start with http://amzn.com/w/ followed by anything. But what ever I enter I get the error message.

```
validates :wl_url, format: { with: /\A(http:\/\/amzn\.com\/w\/)+([a-z0-9]*)\z/, 
  message: 'Please make sure the Wish List code starts with http://amzn.com/w/, if unsure see "how it works" page for instructions.'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
validates_format_of :wl_url, :with => /\A(http:\/\/amzn\.com\/w\/)+([a-z0-9]*)\z/i, :message => "Please make sure the Wish List code starts with http://amzn.com/w/, if unsure see "how it works" page for instructions."
```